# How can i update database Mysql in JSP file?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%  

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/members", "root", "");


        Statement st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

        String s1 = request.getParameter("fname");
        String s2 = (String)request.getParameter("password");
        String mySQL = "SELECT * FROM   allusers WHERE fname='" + s1 +"' and password='" + s2 + "'";


        ResultSet oRS = st.executeQuery(mySQL);
        if (oRS.next())
        {
            //System.out.print("Hey");
            String s3 = (String)request.getParameter("lname");
            String s4 = (String)request.getParameter("mail");
            String s5 = (String)request.getParameter("gender");
            String s6 = (String)request.getParameter("religen");
            oRS.moveToInsertRow();
            mySQL = "UPDATE allusers SET lname='"+ s3 +"', mail='"+ s4 +"', gender='"+ s5 +"', religen='"+ s6 +"' WHERE fname='"+ s1 +"' ";
            oRS = st.executeQuery(mySQL);
            response.sendRedirect("didthat.jsp");
        }
        else {
            response.sendRedirect("notreg.jsp");
        } 
    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Error in connecting");
    } // the connection is closed

%>
```

I did this and its doesn't works, so i put flags and the error is in the mySQL row (below `oRS.moveToInsetRow()`).

please help me fix this error, the error i get is:
Can not issue data manipulation statements with `executeQuery()`.
Error in connecting

thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

**executeQuery()** method doesn't work for update of Statement type.
For Update use **executeUpdate(String query)**

Try using PreparedStatement, because **executeQuery()** works only in PreparedStatement for update.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the following line,

```
String mySQL = "UPDATE allusers SET lname='"+ s3 +"', mail='"+ s4 +"', gender='"+ s5 +"', religen='"+ s6 +"' WHERE fname='"+ s1 +"' ";
ResultSet oRS = st.executeQuery(mySQL);
```

You should use an instance of `PreparedStatement`:
    PreparedStatement st = null;

```
String mySQL = "UPDATE allusers SET lname=?, mail=?, gender=? religen=? WHERE fname=? ";

st = connection.prepareStatement(mySQL);
st.setString(1, s3);
st.setString(2, s4);
st.setString(3, s5);
st.setString(4, s6);
st.setString(5, s1);

st.executeUpdate(mySQL);
```

Code above assumes that all the columns are of type `String` and the variables s1, s2 etc hold the values to be used in the update query.

Hope that helps!!!